# Invalid Output Tensor Index: 1

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite

my yolov5m.pt model is converted into tflite and after integrating it into android studio i always got this error "Invalid Output Tensor Index:1.
This is the code

```
   Map<Integer,Object> output_map=new TreeMap<>();

        float[][][]boxes =new float[1][25200][15];
        float[][] scores=new float[1][25200];
        float[][] classes=new float[1][25200];

        output_map.put(0,boxes);
        output_map.put(1,classes);
        output_map.put(2,scores);

        interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(input,output_map);

        Object value=output_map.get(0);
        Object Object_class=output_map.get(1);
        Object score=output_map.get(2);
```

and got the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid output Tensor index: 1
```